# Connectivity Manager Always Detects there is Internet Connection

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

Am trying to check if my device is connected to internet before I do operations require connection. Currently am using Android Virtual Device with codes below. The Strange thing is, it always reports true (Which means there is internet connection) even when I expect it to return false. This causes problems to my App. I have tried many other solution including example on Android Developer Documentation with same result. What am I doing wrong?

Note I have passed both activity and Activity::getApplicationContext as Context objects with no success.

```
     public boolean isConnectedToInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        Log.v(this.getClass().getName(), info[i].toString());
                        return true;
                    }

        }
        return false;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code have no problem. The issue was that I tried to disable host machine (Laptop) Internet instead of the phone itself. Just disable both mobile data and wifi connections via setting (in AVD) and then it will work

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                     Context context = getApplicationContext();
                                     ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                                     NetworkInfo networkInfo = null;
                                         networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                                         if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
                                         {
                                             //Perform operation what yyou want to perform when you got Internet connection

                                         } 
                                    }
                            });
                            Thread.sleep(10000);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
```

Hope this may help you!